# Quickly retrieving specific files from a directory

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a website in which my client would like to upload invoices for his customers (PDF) to a directory on the webserver.  Then, when a client logs in, they could see all their invoices and sort by date.

Since he has to upload about 1000 invoices each month, I'm trying to think of the best way to accomplish this.  He does not want to upload an invoice one by one.  He'd rather just upload 100 at a time or so.  I'm thinking that each invoice will need to have the client's account number and date in the file name to help in this process.  Yet, even with that, if there are thousands of invoices, there's probably going to have to be some automatic linking of the file path to a database once all these invoices are uploaded.

Anyone have a good idea in mind to get this project running?

Comment: How does the upload itself work? You cannot expect him to manually upload 1000 files...

Comment: They will upload the invoices by FTP to a pre-defined directory.

Comment: Well if it really has to be the 70th FTP protocol with all its annoying side effects then at least add some encryption so that no everyone can read the login details. So try to use FTPS or, much better, SFTP. However the latter requires a different client and server software. However the upload is done, try to avoid that the customer has to trigger an import process himself. You would have to ask hm to use two different applications, then it might even make more sense to write a small "import client" yourself (and use http for upload and communication).

Comment: Yes, FTPS or SFTP will be the way to go.  I want this process to be simple for the client and they already FTP, so that should be a no brainer.  Initiating a process is something I'd rather them not worry about.  Maybe a cron job that hunts the recently uploaded PDFs?

Comment: Sure, a cron job is easy, but also little elegant. You could also configure the PAM system to start that import job each time a customer logs out.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the "yet unloaded" PDFs in a directory.  Grab the account number, invoice number, and date from the PDFs (OCR or if they still contain the text) and use these to add entries to your database.

Assuming you're not loading the PDFs into the database, move them to their permanent location after the database insert works.

Better yet - aren't you generating the PDFs from the database in the first place?  Add this archival step as part of the PDF generation process.

Comment: The client will upload the PDFs via FTP to the webserver.

So what you're saying is that I have a script which reads the text in the PDF?  Maybe I can read the metadata instead?

Comment: Also, I guess the client would first upload the PDFs to a directory and then trigger a process that would search the directory for all the newly uploaded PDFs?

Comment: Well what would the "metadata" of those PDF files contain? And where do you get it from?

Comment: My thoughts is that I need to know the date of the invoice and the account number of the company whom the invoice is for. I'm not too familiar with pulling that info from OCR, but the main reason I wouldn't want to use OCR is in case the format of the invoice ever changed. Instead, if I ask the client to make sure all invoice file names use a unique format like ACCOUNT_NUM-DATE.pdf, then I can pull the info from there. Tough part is writing a script that finds all the recently uploaded PDFs and stores their file paths in a database linked to the company's account.

Comment: On unix, `find` is your friend.  Also, have an 'upload' directory and then move the files to their permanent home as part of processing.  That will keep them from using FTP to delete the files, too.

Comment: The script has to be PHP based and I do not have access to exec commands.  I can use some PHP commands to query for new files though.  As far as moving the files to a permanent directory, it's going to have to be all automated.  They don't want to pay for monthly service, lol.